# How do I use rewrite in Nginx to convert an Apache redirect rule?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need some help to convert .htaccess apache rewrite to Nginx.

My WordPress website has this URL structure:

```
https://domain.com/our-office/laos/
```

And I need to change to:

```
https://domain.com/laos/
```

I did that easily with Apache and .htaccess with:

```
Redirect 301 /our-office/laos /laos/
```

But now that I moved to Nginx, I cannot get the same results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rewrite with 'permanent' keyword, for example:

```
rewrite  ^/our-office/laos/(.*)$  https://domain.com/laos/$1 permanent;
```

Comment: Note that the `return` directive can also be used. I'm not completely clear on when which should be used and why, but there is a discussion on [Taxing Rewrites](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Taxing_Rewrites) at nginx.org.

Comment: @Paul There's no reason to use it there. The return directive should be used when a rewrite is not necessary, i.e. when no specific part of the original URI is captured. In this case he can't use a return directly because a subpart needs to be extracted. He would need a map and a location and so it's better for concision to use a rewrite alone